# iOS/Android Detect and Redirect

Tags: javascript, redirect, operating-system

Newbie in js so take me slow:D
Need to make a redirection based on what os the user is using. If ios redirect to x, if android redirect to y, else..stay on the original address. 
My question:

Are these snippets enough?

```
<script type="text/javascript"> // <![CDATA[
    if ( (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Android') != -1) ) {
        document.location = "y";
    } // ]]>
</script>

<script type="text/javascript"> // <![CDATA[
    if ((navigator.userAgent.indexOf('iPhone') != -1) || (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('iPod') != -1) || (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('iPad') != -1)) {
        document.location = "x";
    } // ]]>
</script>
```

Thank you!:D

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
var isMobile = {
        Android: function() {
            return navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i);
        },
        BlackBerry: function() {
            return navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i);
        },
        iOS: function() {
            return navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone|iPad|iPod/i);
        },
        Opera: function() {
            return navigator.userAgent.match(/Opera Mini/i);
        },
        Windows: function() {
            return navigator.userAgent.match(/IEMobile/i);
        },
        any: function() {
            return (isMobile.Android() || isMobile.BlackBerry() || isMobile.iOS() || isMobile.Opera() || isMobile.Windows());
        }

    };



if ( isMobile.Android() ) {
        document.location.href = "y";
    }
else if(isMobile.iOS())
{
document.location.href="x";
}
```

Comment: Curious about a php version:D Managed to find something but won't work:(

Comment: not working in android 5.0.1/chrome 46.0 unless `document.location.href = "y";` bound within a click event

Answer (score 1):

Other way to redirect to Apple store, google play or windows store to download application.

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script>
      function getMobileOS() {
        var userAgent = navigator.userAgent || navigator.vendor || window.opera;

        // Windows Phone must come first because its UA also contains "Android"
        if (/windows phone/i.test(userAgent)) {
          return "Windows Phone";
        }

        // Android detection 
        if (/Android/i.test(userAgent)) {
          return "Android";
        }

        // iOS detection 
        if (/iPad|iPhone|iPod/.test(userAgent) && !window.MSStream) {
          return "iOS";
        }
        return false;
      }

      function DetectAndRedirect() {
        if (getMobileOS() == "Android") {
          window.location.href = "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.your.AppName";
        }
        if (getMobileOS() == "iOS") {
          window.location.href = "https://apps.apple.com/US/app/idOfYourAPP";
        }
        if (getMobileOS() == "Windows Phone") {
          window.location.href = "https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/NameOfYourAPP";
        }
        if (!getMobileOS()) {
          document.getElementById('not-mobile').innerHTML = "if not mobile show page with all links to store";
        }
      };
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="DetectAndRedirect()">
    <div id="not-mobile"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Authur's solution is much better and more compatible to modern devices.

In case you are using some website builder like Webflow, Wix or else and you cannot add `onload` attribute to `body`, you can add this script to run the function.

```
window.onload = function () {
  DetectAndRedirect();
};
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32553370)