# iOS Android - How to create a download link for an app?

Tags: android, ios, google-play, app-store

Can anyone please guide me. I want to create a link that directs to App Store and Google Play Store and also make a record where the link is clicked from.

the link might look something like this:

```
http://myapp.com/get
```

Is there a place where I can create this? Or do I have to do it all by myself?

Answer (score 1):

[Smarturl](http://smarturl.it) will do it for you but the url will be `http://smarturl.it/blahblahblah`. If you want to implement it on your website, you have to do it by yourself. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17522147/ios-android-detect-and-redirect) might help you.

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you need a kind of DeepLink. For example you can take a look at [branch.io](https://branch.io/what-is-deep-linking/) or [Firebase Dynamic Links](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links)